# Iterate a multi-threaded list without synchronizing the entire process

Tags: java, multithreading, list, iterator, synchronization

I have multi-threading code and a single array which all the threads should access it and only one could modify it(add,remove,..) or modify an object in it 
I need a secure way to let the threads access it.. 
I read about the lock mutex synchronization , synchronized list , copyonwritearraylist and volatile.

There will be lots of iterations so I can't put synchronized outside the loop like that:

```
synchronized (list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    //Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

because I'll lose the advantage of multithreading And my lists size may reach around 1000 so I can't lock the whole list while iteration  on all those items

I have also read about CopyOnWriteArrayList that It is suitable for situations when the list is used for iteration not to be modified

So what is the best solution to use for a situation like mine

Comment: Note: I recommend using spaces (but really an editor that auto-indents and adds spaces on tab-presses) and not tabs. It also makes copying to SO easier.

Comment: So you have a situation that requires high concurrency, but also requires you to iterate through all of a list of objects.  Honestly, you have to design your program so that it *CAN BE MADE* concurrent.  As it is, we only know that you need to iterate a list, so that's all we can advise you to do.

Comment: You have more reads, writes or both ? I am looking it more from a design perspective than Java implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` may actually be what you want.  It allows you to iterate over a snapshot of the list as it existed at some point in time.  It may not be identical to the list as it is *now*, but do you really need it to be?

Think about it this way.  A thread iterating over the list and the thread modifying the list could interleave their operations in a variety of ways, none of which is wrong.  One possibility is that the iterating thread could iterate over the entire list before the modifying thread is ever scheduled to run.  Another possibility is that the iterating thread will get halfway through the list before it is modified.  Propagating the changes to all existing iterators would be a complex and expensive operation, and you'd have to carefully define what an iterator does, for example, when something is inserted below its current position.  And all this complexity would not make the program any more correct, because the behavior would be identical to `CopyOnWriteArrayList` if the threads just happened to be scheduled in a slightly different way.

This is a pattern you will encounter often in efficient, highly concurrent programs.  The important thing is that a thread is operating on a *valid snapshot* of an object, not necessarily the current version of the object as it is known to some other thread.

Comment: It should be noted (from the java doc): "This is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations"

Comment: @Kevin I'm really confused, could you please explain your answer with an example so I can understand how should I use this pattern

Comment: What don't you understand about the example and explanation I already gave you?